# How to start with Spring and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, vaadin

What I need to do is simple Spring + Hibernate application based on Vaadin framework.
I'm quite new in java. I watched dozens of hours tutorials, and read all i found. But I cannot find an answer.

I used spring initializr to create base of my application (with JPA, Vaadin, JDBC) checked. I found out how I can start the app if i comment this:

```
SpringApplication.run(RentalApplication.class, args);
```

But its not the case that im looking for, I want to use Spring. 
I stuck on:

```
'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
```

I found tutorials with web.xml configuration, but there is no web.xml in Vaadin project based.

Most of tutorials are outdated, or assumming that yuo know a lot about Hibernate and Spring framework already.

Comment: Post the entire stack trace of the error please.

Comment: Have you added a dependency to the database jdbc driver in your pom.xml?

Comment: Yea i added, jdbc4 I created DAO, models, beans config in .xml. I can run application if i comment Spring bootstrap. But thats not the case.

Comment: Again, post the stack trace if you want an accurate response but I'm guessing you haven't given Spring boot the proper configuration to connect to your database. You need to add the properties "spring.datasource.url" and "spring.jpa.database-platform" to your application.properties.

Comment: Thanks, that solve my problem. Im wondering why nobody mention in tutorials that yuo can do this in spring application.properties ...

Comment: Tutorials here: https://spring.io/guides The `application.properties` is a standard thing from Spring Boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete the answer, when not using an embedded database such as H2, for Spring Boot to work with JDBC and JPA, it also needs settings in the Spring Boot config file: application.properties (or application.yml if using yml)

For example for PostgreSQL:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase
spring.datasource.username=myusername
spring.datasource.password=mypassword
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Probably the tutorials you have found online use an H2 database and that's why they don't include these settings.

In any case, of course you also need the dependency to JDBC driver (e.g. in pom.xml)

By the way, here is a link to the official documentation where it is explained in detail:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-configure-datasource

And the specific section about embedded databases:

> Spring Boot can auto-configure embedded H2, HSQL and Derby databases. You don’t need to provide any connection URLs, simply include a build dependency to the embedded database that you want to use.